# Power App form patching. My SQL connection

Tags: powerapps

I am moving an Excel spreadsheet to a SQL database with view and edit forms. I have created few screens and function buttons.

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G22b7.png)

Add Forms are linked to the table via On Premise gateway and they are working as expected using PATCH statement. However after adding more forms, i am receiving back runtime error saying

```
"body": {
"status": 400,
"message": "A value must be provided for item.\r\nclientRequestId: d0045f72-b8e2-46f2-ad9e-eac1a4157796",
"error": {
  "message": "A value must be provided for item."
},
"source": "sql-uks.logic-ase-uksouth.p.azurewebsites.net"
```

}

My patch statement is not different from others that works:

Working one:

```
Patch(PreRequisites, Defaults(PreRequisites),
```

{Named_Contact:DataCardValue1.Text,
Pre_requisites_CheckList:DataCardValue2.Text,
RFC_Number:DataCardValue3.Text,
Target_Date:DataCardValue4.SelectedDate,
Team_Responsible:DataCardValue5.Text});
Notify("Record Added Your Grace",NotificationType.Success)

Runtime error one:

```
Patch(Testing, Defaults(Testing),
```

{Date:DataCardValue17.SelectedDate,
Actual_Result:DataCardValue24.Text,
Activity:DataCardValue25.Text,
Description:DataCardValue26.Text,
Expected_Result:DataCardValue27,
Named_Contact:DataCardValue29.Text,
Notes:DataCardValue30.Text,
Owner:DataCardValue31.Text,
Pre_Req:DataCardValue32.Text,
Secondary_Resource:DataCardValue33.Text,
Status:DataCardValue34.Text,
Test_Outcome:DataCardValue35.Text,
Test_Resource:DataCardValue36.Text,
Time:DataCardValue37.Text});
Notify("Record Added Your Grace",NotificationType.Success, 3)

I did checked if there is any required field

[DB field requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bghUP.png)

Currently i exhausted all resource i could find on net, and i am stuck with this. Could someone could help me with finding root cause of this issue? Also please let me know if more information is needed.

EDIT:
I have noticed that there is one empty field returned from DB "@odata.etag"

```
"value": [
  {
    "@odata.etag": "",
    "ItemInternalId": "02eb0cf5-b83a-44f4-ba4a-6b3f9b70cfb9",
    "Date": "2021-12-22T00:00:00Z",
    "Time": "PT23H59M",
    "Status": "Due",
    "Activity": "test to test connection",
    "Owner": "mua",
    "Named_Contact": "mua",
    "RFC_Number": "RFCnot your business",
    "Notes": "notes",
    "ID": 1
  }
]
```

Could you please advise if this can be removed, and if yes... how?